# Find gateway address in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, networking, route

I want to find my gateway address in CentOS 7.
The command

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network[/tt]
```

returns the following:

```
##created by anaconda
```

So I start to install os-installer

```
sudo yum install epel-release

sudo yum install snapd

sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket

sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap

sudo snap install easy-installer --beta
```

but I receive this error

```
Buffer 1/0 error on dev loop0, logical block 0 ,asymc page read
cannot install "east-installer" : presistent network error: post
```

Comment: error doesn't seems to be related to gateway, dynamic information about network is found using `ip` (try `ip r s`). what is, in your mind, relationship between gateway and snap ?

Comment: @Archemar What does the 's' option do?  I didn't see it in the man pages.  And, the command shows the exact same output if I run it with or without the 's'.

Comment: `s` in `ip r s` (or `ip a s`) stand for show (and opposed to set/delete etc ...). I agree now, it seems useless (I use it out of habbit). (you get them using `ip route help`or `ip address help`)